# How to add Import-Package instructions for runtime dependencies?

Tags: osgi, gradle, bnd

I'm building an OSGi jar using Gradle, and I'm having a bit of trouble with the manifest. Here's an excerpt from my build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'osgi'

jar {
    baseName = 'awesome'
    manifest {
        name = 'An Awesome Application'
        symbolicName = 'com.example.awesome'
//        instruction 'Import-Package', 'org.springframework.orm'
    }
}
```

Using the above, Gradle detects my dependencies and adds an `Import-Package` with all my compile-time dependencies. But say my application has a runtime dependency on `org.springframework.orm` as well, how do I tell Gradle to include that as an argument in `Import-Package`?

With the commented row above uncommented, the generated `Import-Package` instruction specifies *only* `org.springframework.orm`. This confuses me, since [the Gradle documentation for OsgiManifest](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/osgi/OsgiManifest.html#instruction%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29) states

> `OsgiManifest instruction(String name, String... values)`
>
> Adds arguments to an instruction. If the instruction does not exists,
>   it is created. If it does exists, the arguments are appended to the
>   existing arguments.

This doesn't seem to apply for the auto-detected `Import-Package` arguments, however. If I specify `instruction 'Import-Package', 'my.dependency.1'` and so on, and print `jar.manifest.instructions` in between, I can see how they are added in sequence, and they all appear in the generated manifest, but it seems that Gradle's OSGi plugin does not add the auto-detected arguments if `Import-Package` is manually specified.

### TL;DR:

- If I do not manually specify the `Import-Package` instruction, it is auto-generated with all my compile-time dependencies, but not runtime dependencies.
- If I do `manifest { instruction 'Import-Package', 'org.springframework.orm' }`, then the compile-time dependencies are not automatically included.

How can I tell Gradle my runtime dependencies so they can be added to `Import-Package`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Gradle bnd plugin, but I am familiar with bnd.

The default value of `Import-Package` in bnd instruction is `*`. The means: match against all of the generated imports. If you specify a single value for `Import-Package` then it overrides the `*` and becomes the sole import. Therefore your `Import-Package` instruction nearly always should end with a catch-all `*` in the last position.

Taking a guess at how this would translate to Groovy/Gradle, I suggest the following:

`instruction 'Import-Package', 'org.springframework.orm', '*'`

Comment: Spot on! As expected from the documentation, `instruction 'Import-Package', '*'` on its own row also works.