# manifest first OSGi build with gradle - migrating from ant to Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, manifest.mf

Is there manifest first
http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Tooling_Approaches
gradle plugin for OSGi? Or how to do it with gradle?

There's big old project for OSGi container with many project having complicated relation declared in MANIFEST.MF. The build is long.
Now we want to simplify things and adopt Gradle. But first without breaking things and keeping ant and gradle builds in parallel for some time.
However what I see is gradle suggesting define MANIFEST inside `build.gradle`. 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/osgi_plugin.html
That would make a lot of copy work.

UPDATE There are close to 100 modules with a lot of dependencies information between modules and for nested jar. On average MANIFEST.MF length is about 50 lines (varies from 20 to 300 lines).
How to bundle nested jar's is [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36336709/gradle-to-bundle-nested-jar-dependencies-into-module-output-jar).
This question is about using existing MANIFEST.MF files. All plugins I saw use `bnd` that is exactly contrary to manifest first approach.

Comment: If you are writing your manifests by hand then you can pass them directly to the JAR task. Is there something more to it that I'm missing?

Comment: How to pass existing MANIFEST.MF file to jar task? I see as now the only way is to copy information from MANIFEST.MF into `build.gradle` jar section, that is huge monkey work. Those files may change before gradle build will start working and accepted as main delivery method.

Comment: I don't have enough Gradle knowledge to answer. The `jar` command from the JDK takes a manifest file using the `-m` switch, I would be very surprised if the Gradle task did not expose that option in some way.

Comment: This is about OSGi additional properties, that JDK can't know. And the question is can gradle read OSGi dependencies on other bundles (OSGi jars)

Comment: The JDK doesn't need to know. The `jar` command allows a predefined manifest to be supplied as a file. Quickly checking the Gradle docs, it looks like the Jar task has a `manifest` property that you can use. Something like `Manifest.from(filename)`.

Comment: You gave me at least 2 ideas already. Great.

Comment: Are you stuck on Gradle?
Why not use Maven. Then you can use the standard maven goals for creating osgi manifests etc.

Comment: Because Gradle is better :) !

Comment: @Richard If you know Maven plugin that would solve reading dependencies information, please add as an answer. I could not find such plugin neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of April 2016 there's no Manifest-first approach in Maven or Gradle build tools for OSGi.

While for Eclipse plugins (that are also valid OSGi bundles) there is maven/[tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) build, that is standard within Eclipse Foundation, it is not really of help for general OSGi projects.

Oposite to Manifest-first is Manifest generation, and there is only one tool `bnd`, that initially was for manifest creation, then grew into full bundle jar builder and now has [BndTools Eclipse integration](http://bndtools.org/), looking similar to Maven/Gradle integration managing dependencies.

I would recommend to keep `bnd` instructions in external standard `bnd.bnd` file and not to put it inside build script. `*.bnd` files are similar to usual Java `.properties` files, so in Eclipse IDE right-click, Open with -> Other ... select `Properties File Editor` check "Use this editor for.." and check "Use this editor for all '*.nbd' files"

### For Gradle

- [Gradle OSGi Plugin] (standard, built-in)(https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/osgi_plugin.html) gives only manifest manipulation, so [GRADLE-1107 "OSGi instruction `Include-Resource` not working"](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1107) is
  open issue since 2010
- [Gradle Bundle Plugin](https://github.com/TomDmitriev/gradle-bundle-plugin) allows you to create OSGI bundles. Its main difference from the Gradle OSGI Plugin is that it uses the bnd tool to generate not only a manifest but a whole jar.
- [`osgi-run`](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/osgi-run) "Osgi-Run - A Gradle plugin to make the development of modular applications using OSGi completely painless"

### For maven

- `maven-bundle-plugin`
  aka [Apache Felix Maven Bundle Plugin (BND)](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)
  is [“Maven first” approach](http://bnd.bndtools.org/tools/maven-felix.html)
- `bnd-maven-plugin` [announce and 2 plugins comparison](http://njbartlett.name/2015/03/27/announcing-bnd-maven-plugin.html)

All bnd-based tools are now [collected](https://github.com/bndtools/bnd.manual/tree/gh-pages/_tools) on http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/700-tools.html

There are some examples in https://github.com/paulvi/OSGiBuildExamples

Note: link http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Tooling_Approaches has been in "The OSGi Community Wiki was unfortunately hacked and is currently unavailable.
" status for more than a week, while this question was opened.

Sadly @Richard gave up too early to receive some thanks as well (for mentioning maven)

Answer (score 10):

Gradle has an `OsgiManifest` class, which is an extended jar manifest:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/osgi/OsgiManifest.html

There is a post on StackOverflow that shows similar usage:

[How to add Import-Package instructions for runtime dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298263/how-to-add-import-package-instructions-for-runtime-dependencies)

The relevant gradle block looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'osgi'

jar {
    baseName = 'awesome'
    manifest {
        name = 'An Awesome Application'
        symbolicName = 'com.example.awesome'
        instruction 'Import-Package', 'org.springframework.orm', '*'
    }
}
```

If you have existing manifests and would like to use your own custom files, you can do this by setting the manifest file location within the jar closure:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        def manif = "${resourcesDir}/MANIFEST.MF"
        if (new File(manif).exists()) {
            from file(manif)
        }
        else{
            name = 'overwrittenSpecialOsgiName'
            instruction 'Private-Package', 'org.mycomp.somepackage'
            instruction 'Bundle-Vendor', 'MyCompany'
            instruction 'Bundle-Description', 'Platform2: Metrics' 
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation for Gradle's manifest can be found here:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html

**For your 'other question':**

There are additional Gradle plugins for building OSGI bundles, in some cases, including dependencies from other OSGI bundles.

For one example, there is the [Gradle Bundle Plugin](https://github.com/TomDmitriev/gradle-bundle-plugin), which uses the bnd tool and allows you to specify to include transitive-dependencies and even exclude unwanted ones.
As an example:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Bundle Quickstart',     // Will be added to manifest
                     'Import-Package': '*'  // Will be overwritten by the instuctions below
    }
}

bundle {
    includeTransitiveDependencies = true

    instructions << [
        'Bundle-Activator': 'foo.bar.MyBundleActivator',
        'Import-Package': 'foo.*',
        '-sources': true
    ]

    instruction 'Export-Package', '*' // Specify an individual instruction
    instruction '-wab', ''
}
```

There is also the [Gradle osgi-run plugin](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/osgi-run), which includes transitive dependencies by default:

```
dependencies {
    // all your usual dependencies
    ...

    osgiRuntime( "your:dependency:1.0" ) {
        transitive = false // transitive dependencies not included in OSGi runtime
    }
}
```

Hopefully that's enough to get you going.

Comment: This is already nice answer (upvoted), but it does not address problem of taking all dependencies information, e.g. between modules, and what we have of nested jars.

Comment: Paul, your last comment. Is this related to solving the 'Other question' you have posted? I'm trying to get a clear picture of what exactly you want to help offer additional suggestions.

Comment: Once dependencies information is there, bundle can be built with or without nested jar's, that is other questions. At least for gradle build to be DONE, compilation should pass, i.e. all dependencies from MANIFEST.MF files should be visible to compiler. I am not expert of all possible dependencies declaration within MANIFEST, there are at least package and bundle dependencies.

Comment: Paul, I have added more information to the answer for a couple of other osgi plugins I found. However, I'm thinking (correct me if I am wrong) that what you may need is to use the default OSGI plugin, but after adding your 50+ OSGI modules as dependencies themselves (are they in a common lib?), then you are saying you need to then find information in each modules manifest to explicitly add each modules manifest declared dependencies to the general build classpath as well in order for your build to succeed. Thoughts or clarifications?

Comment: I am researching on my own, trying out all plugins found by osgi query. I have not tried yet osgi-run, the Gradle Bundle Plugin uses `bnd`, the wuff is monstrous and not updated for a while. What I need first is get off from ant build and get the same build result, before starting changes using new build tool.